# Scaling a 1% width div up 100 times doesn't cover the full width of the parent

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a progress bar.

You'd think that a div with a width of 1% scaled up horizontally 100 times would span the width of its parent, but it doesn't. The amount of space left seams to depend on my window size, so I think this might be a rounding issue in the browser. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

I'm changing the progress of this bar quite often, so I don't want to change the bar's width property every time, as that would cause [performance issues](http://csstriggers.com/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
#progress {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: : 0;
  width: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: scale(100, 1);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="progress">
  </div>
</div>
```

I also made a codepen to demonstrate this issue: http://codepen.io/bigblind/pen/Zbozjv

Comment: Just transition from width 1% to width 100%, why are you using scaling?

Comment: For performance. Changing the width means that the browser needs to recalculate the layout and repaint. Doing that about 5 times per second would really cause performance issues.

Comment: Sounds like a premature optimization to me, but ymmv.

Comment: Believe me, it's not premature, I was having serious performance issues, and switching to transformations fixed a lot of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The amount of space left seams to depend on my window size, so I think
>   this might be a rounding issue in the browser.

Yes. It is.

> I don't want to change the bar's width property every time

I am not trying to debate the performance thingy here, but just trying to concentrate on the problem that if not `width` then what property could be used?

Well, you could just turn your progress on its head. Instead of the `#progress` div expanding to show the amount of progress, slide it out of the way to reveal the background `#container` div to show the amount of progress. Use the `translate` to slide the progress away.

*In the demo below, hover to see the transform in effect.*

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y2o7yub9/1**

**Demo Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body { width: 100%; }
#container{
    background-color: yellow; position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0;
    height: 100px; width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;
}
#progress{
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translateX(0%); transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#container:hover > div { transform: translateX(100%); }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Looks to me that there is a rounding issue.

On a 1920 pixel monitor, 1% gets translated to 19.188 pixels which gets rounded down to 19 pixels

19 pixels * 100 = 1900 pixels which leaves a 20 pixel gap.

**More information here**: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Edit: if you rescale your browser, on some widths, the red part is larger, smaller or gone; which confirms the rounding issue.

## Solution

Declare a progress bar with a fixed width : 200px
Initialise it to 2px which can't be rounded up/down